# Moving Background image

Tags: javascript, background-image

Good day every one!

If someone could help me on my problem I'm encountering. I trying to make a website which has a background exactly like this.

http://clearairchallenge.com/

I really like to have a background image (clouds) moving horizontally. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/LwPX6/

hear you have an example :)

```
var intval = null;
var pos = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {


    intval = window.setInterval(moveBg, 200);
});

function moveBg() {

    pos++;

    $(".clouds").css({backgroundPosition: (pos * 10) + "px 0px"});
}
```

greetings :)

Comment: Hey @Mic, i make it work. but another question, how can I make it move smoothly? just like this one:

http://clearairchallenge.com/

you can see it your codes here:

http://bendaggers.com/Zip%20Codes/index.php

and it's working. thank you very much.

Comment: have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/LwPX6/1/ you can play with the values of the repeating time window.setInterval(..., **80**); and the distance which is changed in the moveBg function pos * **x**

Comment: Great! it's really working now! i was adjusting that to 500, i wasnt aware that the lower the value, the faster. lol anyway, thank you for your help @mic.

Comment: no problem :) you can use this 2 values for different speed layers like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
  $('#divId').animate(function() {
                backgroundPosition: '(-5000px 100px)'}, 5);
    });
```

here  background x positions will change from 0 to -5000px during 5 seconds, you can change time and positions px-s to get the desirable result.

**updated** you should use jquery library for that, you can download or use online like

e.g. for using from url, put this in your head secion

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

also you should write this, either in head section or in the body, does not matter, but what is **important** after previous script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#divId').animate(function() {
                backgroundPosition: '(-5000px 100px)'}, 5);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: thanks davo, should i put it inside the <head> tag of my html?

Comment: i also added this on my head tag then inside the <script></script>

Comment: hmmm.. there's something wrong...

http://bendaggers.com/Zip%20Codes/index.php

can you take a look?

Comment: you have to use backgroundPosition for the key name instead of background-position.

Comment: yep @Mic, that's correct. I've modified his code a little. can you double check it here:

http://bendaggers.com/Zip%20Codes/index.php

Comment: so you should read the description of animate: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ the duration is only 5 ms . So you will never see any movement. You need a timer event, an interval what goes on all the time. animate works only one times. i don't know what you can use in jquery for this but in normal javascript you can use window.setInterval: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: watch my example in the other answer ;) it works in the fiddle :)

Comment: @Davo, thank you for your help but Mic's answer is really working! :)

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery on such a tiny function!

Try...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pos = 0;

    window.setInterval(function(){
      pos++;
      document.getElementsByClassName('clouds')[0].style.backgroundPosition = pos + "px 0px";
    }, 50);
</script>
```

Swap out: `getElementsByClassName('clouds')[0].style` for `getElementById('clouds').style` or I would attach it to the body so simply: `body.style` would do.